# VBA Add loop to add three rows and text below each populated cell

Tags: vba, while-loop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAmbq.png)I'm trying to create a "Loop While" macro to work down column B in an excel file and if the cell is populated, then add three rows after, along with specific text.  Once the rows are added, continue down to the next row and if the cell is populated, then add three rows below that cell. Continue down column until a blank cell is reached

I've tried simple Do While loop but not able to add rows or additional text

Comment: please post the code that got you the closest.  One hint, use a for loop and find the last cell with data then loop backwards.

Answer (score 0):

The text you want to add is the third line.  find the last line with values, then loop backwards.

```
Sub moveandplace()
    Dim textArr() As Variant
    textArr = Array("Test1", "Test2", "Test3") 'change to your desired text.

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change to your sheet name.
        Dim lstrow As Long
        lstrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim i As Long
        For i = lstrow To 2 Step -1
            Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 3).Insert
            .Cells(i + 1, 4).Resize(3).Value = Application.Transpose(textArr)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub forloop()
Dim i As Long

vLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = vLastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "B") <> "" Then
        Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 3).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Range(Cells(i + 1, "B"), Cells(i + 3, "B")) = "your Text"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help so far.  Below is what I currently have and was hoping to add to this macro.  How do I add three rows below the populated cell instead of one row?
                                                                                                                                 
Sub Loop1()
Range("B5").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then

ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=x1Down
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select

Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End If

Loop
End Sub

Comment: Sub Loop1()
Range("B5").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then

ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=x1Down
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=x1Down
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=x1Down
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Select

Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End If

Loop
End Sub

Comment: Hello, this is what I have so far.  It is working to enter the three lines. Now just trying to add in text to the three lines that I've added.

Comment: do you want different text on each line, or the same text on all 3 rows?